# How do I install dateutil package in ironpython?

Tags: python

I would like to use relativedelta () from dateutil package to calculate the time difference between two time stamps.

Comment: What have you tried? If you just don't know how to install packages in python, you should look that up before asking. If you're having problems or errors, we can help but you need to provide much more information about your specific problem or question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pip with IronPython: http://ironpython.net/blog/2014/12/07/pip-in-ironpython-275.html

Comment: Thank you Adrien.